# PySide threading and http downloading

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside

I've had soooo much trouble getting this code to work properly!!!! It runs fine when I debug it step by step, but when running normally it just crashes. Initially I was using a QThread to update the ImagePreview pixmap, but after a whole day of crashes and pain, I changed course. Now it works, in the above scenario when using the debugger, but otherwise I'm stumped. Please help me! What's wrong with this code? Is there another approach I can use? I'm trying to constantly update the image preview with an image downloaded from a url.

```
import sys

import io
import urllib2

from PySide import QtCore, QtGui, QtNetwork
import time

class QDownloadBuffer(QtCore.QBuffer):
    downloadFinished = QtCore.Signal()
    def __init__(self):
        super(QDownloadBuffer, self).__init__()
        self.open(QtCore.QBuffer.ReadWrite)
        self.url = QtCore.QUrl("http://www.google.com.au/images/srpr/logo3w.png")
        self.manager = QtNetwork.QNetworkAccessManager()
        self.request = QtNetwork.QNetworkRequest(self.url)
        self.manager.finished.connect(self.onFinished)

    def startDownload(self):
        print("Starting Download --")
        self.reply = self.manager.get(self.request)

        self.reply.error[QtNetwork.QNetworkReply.NetworkError].connect(self.onError)

    def onFinished(self):
        print("Download Finished -- ")
        print(self.write(self.reply.readAll()))
        self.reply.close()
        self.downloadFinished.emit()

    def onError(self):
        print("oh no there is an error -- ")
        print(self.reply.error())

class ImagePreview(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ImagePreview, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setMinimumSize(50, 50)
        self.text = None
        self.pixmap = None
        self.dl_n = 0


    def paintEvent(self, paintEvent):
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)

        if(self.pixmap):
            painter.drawPixmap(0, 0, self.pixmap)

        if(self.text):
            painter.setPen(QtCore.Qt.blue)
            painter.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Arial", 30))
            painter.drawText(self.rect(), QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter, self.text)

    def startDownload(self):
        self.setText(str(self.dl_n))
        self.dl_n += 1
        print("Starting Download {0}".format(self.dl_n))

        self.db = QDownloadBuffer()
        self.connect(self.db, QtCore.SIGNAL("downloadFinished()"), self, QtCore.SLOT("ondownloadFinished()"))
        self.db.startDownload()

    def ondownloadFinished(self):
        self.paintImage()
        print("download finished?")
        self.db.close()
        self.startDownload()

    def paintImage(self):
        print("Painting")
        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap()
        pixmap.loadFromData(self.db.data())
        self.setPixmap(pixmap)

    def setPixmap(self, pixmap):
        self.pixmap = pixmap
        self.setMinimumSize(pixmap.width(), pixmap.height())
        self.update()

    def setText(self, text):
        self.text = text
        self.update()


class MainWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.imagepreview = ImagePreview()
        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton("Start")
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.imagepreview.startDownload)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        layout.addWidget(self.imagepreview)
        self.setLayout(layout)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    try:
        app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    except RuntimeError:
        pass

    mainwindow = MainWindow()
    mainwindow.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are calling `self.startDownload()` from slot (signal handler). So you are not returning control to Qt main loop (or something like this). Proper way is to call it as deferred event, e.g. by calling it through [`QTimer.singleShot`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtimer.html#singleShot):

```
def ondownloadFinished(self):
    self.paintImage()
    print("download finished?")
    self.db.close()
    QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, self.startDownload)
```

Note that `singleShot` with `msec` set to 0:

```
QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, self.startDownload)
```

is the same as:

```
QtCore.QMetaObject.invokeMethod(self, 'startDownload',  QtCore.Qt.QueuedConnection)
```

([source](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/corelib/kernel/qtimer.cpp#n258), [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9043889/pyqt-qtcpsocket-always-in-connectingstate-after-server-restart))

Comment: Just a quick question, do you think it would be wiser to use a separate thread for an operation like this? I've tried very hard to implement it using a thread, but no luck, but if it's worth it I'll give it another shot with this new knowledge in hand.

Comment: @kellpossible, You can do it with threads too. Example http://pastebin.com/b4MD5jKh. But I don't know what is better in your situation.

Comment: You are fantastic. Thankyou so much, I've really be struggling and wading through the internet for a good example of threading that would match my situation, but You've gone and done one yourself!