# Trying to send image from QThread to main or other thread in PyQt

Tags: python, multithreading, image, pyqt, signals

I am trying to display an image from another thread in the main thread or possibly even a new thread. The problem is I cannot get the image to show anywhere else. I am using the thread `_thread` to download the image so it won't freeze the gui but I can't seem to get it out of there properly using QImage or QPixmap.
I know how to use strings and such in signals as shown in the example below but I am not sure how to send the image in a signal properly. I have tried using requests to grab an image url and send it to the main which works but I wasn't able to fetch the string in the main and then just download it there real fast either. That also is not a good option due to freezing the GUI momentarily.

This code is an example that shows that I can do all of the work and download the image in the main if I want to but would rather not.

```
import urllib2
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4.QtCore import QThread, pyqtSignal
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication, QPixmap
import sys

class MainWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__()
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self._Button = QtGui.QPushButton()
        self._Button.setObjectName("_Button")
        self.line_edit = QtGui.QLineEdit()
        self.line_edit.setObjectName("line_edit")
        self.txt_box = QtGui.QTextEdit()
        self.txt_box.setObjectName("txt_Box")
        self.img_label = QtGui.QLabel()
        self.img_label.setObjectName("img_label")
        layout.addWidget(self._Button)
        layout.addWidget(self.line_edit)
        layout.addWidget(self.img_label)
        layout.addWidget(self.txt_box)

        self.pixmap = QPixmap()
        self._thread = test_thread()
        self._Button.clicked.connect(self.start_thread)
        self.get_Text = self._thread.test_Signal.connect(self.line_edit.setText)

        self.urls = 'https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_120x44dp.png'
        data = urllib2.urlopen(self.urls).read()
        self.pixmap.loadFromData(data)
        self.img_label.setPixmap(self.pixmap)

    def start_thread(self):
        self._thread.start()
        self._thread.test_Signal.connect(self.txt_box.setText)


class test_thread(QThread):
    test_Signal = pyqtSignal(str)
    def __init__(self):
        super(test_thread, self).__init__()

    def run(self):
        string = 'This is a test string.'
        self.test_Signal.emit(string)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

And this code shows more of what I am looking to do.

```
import urllib2
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4.QtCore import QThread, pyqtSignal
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication, QPixmap
import sys

class MainWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__()
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self._Button = QtGui.QPushButton()
        self._Button.setObjectName("_Button")
        self.line_edit = QtGui.QLineEdit()
        self.line_edit.setObjectName("line_edit")
        self.txt_box = QtGui.QTextEdit()
        self.txt_box.setObjectName("txt_Box")
        self.img_label = QtGui.QLabel()
        self.img_label.setObjectName("img_label")
        layout.addWidget(self._Button)
        layout.addWidget(self.line_edit)
        layout.addWidget(self.img_label)
        layout.addWidget(self.txt_box)

        self.pixmap = QPixmap()
        self._thread = test_thread()
        self._Button.clicked.connect(self.start_thread)
        self.get_Text = self._thread.test_Signal.connect(self.line_edit.setText)

    "...Send signal here and show image. EX:"
    "...self._thread.image_Signal.connect(self.img_label.setPixmap)...."
    "...or...."
    def show_image_here(self):
        "....Send image here after downloaded in thread...."

    def start_thread(self):
        self._thread.start()
        self._thread.test_Signal.connect(self.txt_box.setText)

class test_thread(QThread):
    test_Signal = pyqtSignal(str)

    "....Example image signal...."
    "....image_Signal = pyqtSignal()...."

    def __init__(self):
        super(test_thread, self).__init__()
        self.pixmap = QPixmap()

    def run(self):
        string = 'This is a test string.'
        self.test_Signal.emit(string)

        self.urls = 'https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_120x44dp.png'
        data = urllib2.urlopen(self.urls).read()
        self.pixmap.loadFromData(data)
        "....Not sure what to do here...."

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Can somebody help me out? Thanks.

Comment: FYI, you can use `QNetworkAccessManager` and `QNetworkRequest` from `QtNetwork` instead of `urllib2`. You can get an exemple [here](https://gist.github.com/bootchk/9025575)

Comment: Yeah I seen that but I didn't get a chance to really look into it yet so for now I am just using urllib2 but i'm definitely going to look into it. Thanks for suggestion and the link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After looking around some more I came across this thread [PySide threading and http downloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9193323/pyside-threading-and-http-downloading)

I wish I had found it sooner because I did a lot of searching before my post. The person who answered that thread `reclosedev` also posted this in the comments:
https://pastebin.com/b4MD5jKh
Which helped me immensely to understand some things better. I used his code and slightly altered it to fit mine and it will work great for what I would like to do.
Here is my full working code using my original example for anyone out there that may find it useful.

```
import urllib2
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt4.QtCore import QThread, pyqtSignal
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication
import sys

class MainWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__()
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self._Button = QtGui.QPushButton()
        self._Button.setObjectName("_Button")
        self.line_edit = QtGui.QLineEdit()
        self.line_edit.setObjectName("line_edit")
        self.txt_box = QtGui.QTextEdit()
        self.txt_box.setObjectName("txt_Box")
        self.img_label = QtGui.QLabel()
        self.img_label.setObjectName("img_label")
        self.imagepreview = ImagePreview()
        layout.addWidget(self._Button)
        layout.addWidget(self.line_edit)
        layout.addWidget(self.img_label)
        layout.addWidget(self.txt_box)
        layout.addWidget(self.imagepreview)

        self._thread = test_thread()
        self._Button.clicked.connect(self.start_thread)
        self._Button.clicked.connect(self.imagepreview.startDownload)
        self.get_Text = self._thread.test_Signal.connect(self.line_edit.setText)

    def start_thread(self):
        self._thread.start()
        self._thread.test_Signal.connect(self.txt_box.setText)


class test_thread(QThread):
    test_Signal = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self):
        super(test_thread, self).__init__()

    def run(self):
        string = 'This is a test string.'
        self.test_Signal.emit(string)


class DownloadThread(QtCore.QThread):
    data_downloaded = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, url):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self)
        self.url = url
        self._data = None

    def run(self):
        self._data = urllib2.urlopen(self.url).read()
        self.data_downloaded.emit()

    def get_data(self):
        return self._data


class ImagePreview(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ImagePreview, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setMinimumSize(50, 50)
        self.pixmap = None

    def paintEvent(self, paintEvent):
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        if (self.pixmap):
            painter.drawPixmap(0, 0, self.pixmap)

    def startDownload(self):
        self.download_thread = DownloadThread('https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_120x44dp.png')
        self.download_thread.start()
        self.download_thread.data_downloaded.connect(self.ondownloadFinished)

    def ondownloadFinished(self):
        self.paintImage()
        print("download finished")

    def paintImage(self):
        print("Painting")
        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap()
        pixmap.loadFromData(self.download_thread.get_data())
        self.setPixmap(pixmap)

    def setPixmap(self, pixmap):
        self.pixmap = pixmap
        self.setMinimumSize(pixmap.width(), pixmap.height())
        self.update()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```